# How to put the username of the logged-in user in the databse each time a form is submitted

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have an application where a user can submit a form which goes into the database (POSTGRES).

I want to be able to automatically send the username of the user logged in to the same database, so i can keep track of who is submitting. (I do not want to put a form line with the username, i want this to be dealt with in the back-end).

what I managed to do is get the user-id, but it stays null, and I do not know how to get the username in the database and to complete it at each submission.

I hope I am clear,

thanls guys.

Here is my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models as db_models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Fertidb(models.Model):
    user = db_models.ManytoManyField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area = models.IntegerField()
    plot = models.FileField(upload_to='KML_FILES', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f' Parcelles de {self.user.username}'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Fertidb


class FertidbForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fertidb
        labels = {
            "plot": "Importez votre fichier KML"
        }
        fields = ['culture', 'area', 'plot']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import FertidbForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

title = 'FERTISAT'


@login_required
def fertisatmap(request):

    mapbox_access_token = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaGFtemFiIiwiYSI6ImNrMHdwYmQ2bzA2OGYzbHB1Z292eGxneDgifQ.rGPQjaoWuOdnq_UdxAfQ_w'
    if request.method == "POST":
        o_form = FertidbForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if o_form.is_valid():
            o_form.save(commit=False)
            o_form.user = request.user.username()
            messages.success(request, f'Vos informations ont été envoyées')
            return redirect('fertisat-map')
    else:
        o_form = FertidbForm()
    context = {'title': title, 'o_form': o_form}
    return render(request, 'fertisat/fertisatmap.html ', context, {'mapbox_access_token': mapbox_access_token})
```

Comment: try this: `request.user` instead, because you're trying to set `user` field of the form so it suppose to be a `User` instance too (request.user)

Comment: This wouldn't "stay null". This would cause a TypeError because `username` is not callable. Plus, you didn't actually save the new object to the database.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I actually would like to have the username displayed in the database. Instead I get the user_id. How would you suggest I do this. (Thanks i have now saved the form)

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your view like so:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import FertidbForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

title = 'FERTISAT'


@login_required
def fertisatmap(request):

    mapbox_access_token = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaGFtemFiIiwiYSI6ImNrMHdwYmQ2bzA2OGYzbHB1Z292eGxneDgifQ.rGPQjaoWuOdnq_UdxAfQ_w'
    if request.method == "POST":
        o_form = FertidbForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if o_form.is_valid():
            fertidb = o_form.save(commit=False)
            fertidb.user = request.user
            fertidb.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Vos informations ont été envoyées')
            return redirect('fertisat-map')
    else:
        o_form = FertidbForm()
    context = {'title': title, 'o_form': o_form}
    return render(request, 'fertisat/fertisatmap.html ', context, {'mapbox_access_token': mapbox_access_token})
```

`(commit=False)` use for creating the model instance without submit to database, then assign current user to your new model instance `fertidb.user = request.user` and then call `.save()` to commit your data to database

---

Btw, `mapbox_access_token` suppose to stay inside `settings.py` in case you want to load it from environment variable when deploy production. like so:

*settings.py*

```py
MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN="pk.eyJ1IjoiaGFtemFiIiwiYSI6ImNrMHdwYmQ2bzA2OGYzbHB1Z292eGxneDgifQ.rGPQjaoWuOdnq_UdxAfQ_w"
```

*views.py*

```py
from django.conf import settings

...
def fertisatmap(request):
    mapbox_access_token = settings.MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

**1. In your Model, you want a `User`, but in your form, you are assigning it the `username`, which I think is a string.**

`user = db_models.ManytoManyField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

and

`o_form.user = request.user.username()`

Just change the second line to `o_form.user = request.user`.

**2. You are not saving the user anyway.**

You have to save your model again after you assign the user.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fo the help guys.

@Toan Quoc Ho thank you I made the modifications but I still have a problem.
The database displays the user_id, but I would like it to display the username.

I guess my problem is in the model file. How do I modify the following, so I get the username in the database.

user=deb_models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete)models.CASCADE) puts the user_id -> I would like to have the username. How do I call it ?

models.py

```
*from django.db import models as db_models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Fertidb(models.Model):
    user = db_models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    culture = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    area = models.IntegerField()
    plot = models.FileField(upload_to='KML_FILES', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f' Parcelles de {self.user.username}'*
```